# Alternate row shading by ID - Conditional Formatting Without Metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

```
02902982085   4   a   ?  <-- blue
02902982085   #   1   r  <-- blue
02902982085   b   $   0  <-- blue
01395235224   w   z   [  <-- yellow
01395235224   a   -   5  <-- yellow
10352351342   r   .   r  <-- blue
10352351342   z   2   -  <-- blue
10352351342   2   x   0  <-- blue
10352351342   q   ]   /  <-- blue
```

I want to alternate light yellow and light blue based on first column. The data is grouped by id, namely the first column. Could have a group of 10+ or just 1. How can this be achieved using native OpenOffice techniques?

---

(*) The way I am currently doing it is using this ruby script to produce boolean values that I can paste into and perform conditional formatting (see image at bottom of page) on in OpenOffice:

```
f = File.readlines("shading.txt") #<-- I just copy and paste a column from spreadsheet to here

$i = 0
$switch = 0

open('shading_out.txt','a'){|g|
while $i < f.size do
    if f[$i] == f[$i+1]
        g.puts ($switch).even?.to_s
    else
        if $i == (f.size-1)
            $switch-=1
            g.puts ($switch).even?.to_s
        else
            g.puts ($switch).even?.to_s
            $switch+=1
        end
    end
    $i += 1 
end
}
```

Which is just ridiculous... Here is the input (which in reality is me just copying and pasting a column from a spreadsheet into a text file) for above program:

### `shading.txt`

```
02902982085
02902982085
02902982085
01395235224
01395235224
10352351342
10352351342
10352351342
10352351342
```

Which would give this output:

### `shading_out.txt`

```
true
true
true
false
false
true
true
true
true
```

I essentially need a way to get a TRUE/FALSE column like this (without using another program and only using OpenOffice formulas/techniques):

```
02902982085   4   a   ?  TRUE  <-- true's would be blue with conditional formatting options (see image below)
02902982085   #   1   r  TRUE
02902982085   b   $   0  TRUE
01395235224   w   z   [  FALSE <-- false's would be yellow, i.e., =NOT($E1) would be true for second conditional (see image below)
01395235224   a   -   5  FALSE
10352351342   r   .   r  TRUE
10352351342   z   2   -  TRUE
10352351342   2   x   0  TRUE
10352351342   q   ]   /  TRUE
```

[image]

So that I can perform conditional formatting based on the "forumla is" option, in this case column E. This way all TRUE entries would be blue, and a second condition would be =NOT($E1) which would make all FALSE entries yellow. OpenOffice calc has no way, as far as I know, to be able to switch the value of a dummy variable upon a switch in ID, namely the two FALSE instances, which is why I'm using ruby...

---

[image]

Comment: In other words, I need a formula that can produce these boolean values to match with groups of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the problem, you can write something like
"IF(A2=A1;B1;NOT(B1))"
in cell B2, where A is the column with ID, and B the true/false column.

Comment: Try again. I don't think you understand yet.